# The highlight controls of axAcroPDF are disabled

Tags: c#, pdf, axacropdf

I am try to use axAcroPDF COM to display PDF file on my form , select text and highlight them.
The PDF page can be rendered correctly. And I have noticed there are some buttons stay at right of the form , but they are all gray ,so I can not click these buttons to make the selected content highlight.

I have tested , to load the same PDF file with Adobe Reader, I can use all the function normally.
I also tryed to use setCurrentHighLight() but is not work.

Please help me to solve this problem , Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to make `setCurrentHighLight()` work?